# GAE, JDO, count() doesn't work?

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, jdo

On GAE with Spring/JDO after saving 2 entities (in transaction).
On calling `getById` - entities fetched from data storage.
On calling `getCount()` returns "0"
and - on calling `getAll()` - returns empty collection.

```
 @Override
 public Long getCount() {
  return ((Integer) getJdoTemplate().execute(new JdoCallback() {
   @Override
   public Object doInJdo(PersistenceManager pm) throws JDOException {
    Query q = pm.newQuery(getPersistentClass());
    q.setResult("count(this)");
    return q.execute();
   }
  })).longValue();
 }

 @Override
 public void saveOrUpdate(T entity) {
  getJdoTemplate().makePersistent(entity);
 }

 @Override
 public List<T> getAll() {
  return new ArrayList<T>(getJdoTemplate().find(getPersistentClass()));
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's implementation of JDO does not currently support aggregates AFAIK.  Try keeping track of the count by updating some other entity every time you persist a new entity.  If you are doing frequent writes, you'll want a "[sharded](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html)" counter.

Your question is pretty close to [this one,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894376/how-do-i-get-a-count-of-all-entries-of-a-given-type-stored-in-google-appengines) so reading those answers may help.

Answer (score 0):

count() is actually implemented in GAE/J's plugin, as seen here
http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/src/org/datanucleus/store/appengine/query/DatastoreQuery.java#341

If you have a problem with it then suggest that you provide a testcase to Google and raise an issue on their issue tracker for their GAE/J DN plugin ("Issues" on the linked page)

Comment: I'm unsure what you're linking to on that page. is fulfillBatchDeleteQuery significant?

Comment: Since their code is updated and that screws up links ... using latest code http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/src/org/datanucleus/store/appengine/query/DatastoreQuery.java#361 -  Fact remains, they support count(), as can be seen by a simple review of that code ... should anyone bother to do such a thing

Comment: Hahaha, and now the link is dead again.